# PHP multiply two multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a two multidimensional arrays

**Array 1**

```
Array(
    "2" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 2,
            "id" => 2
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 1,
            "id" => 1
        ),

    "3" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 1,
            "id" => 3
        ));
```

**Array 2**

```
Array(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "2Bed Room",
            "room" => 6,
            "bed" => 12,
            "price" => 2800,
            "available_room" => 6,
            "available_bed" => 12,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "3Bed Room",
            "room" => 12,
            "bed" => 36,
            "price" => 3800,
            "available_room" => 12,
            "available_bed" => 36,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "Dormitory",
            "room" => 8,
            "bed" => 16,
            "price" => 750,
            "available_room" => 8,
            "available_bed" => 16,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ));
```

I want to multiply values based on id.

For example `Array 1` contains `[id] => 2`

and `Array 2` having same id `[id] => 2`.

If the requirements meet, then multiple `Array 1` quantity to `Array 2` price
and return this in array format.

thanks for your replay

Comment: And what you have tried?

Comment: You need some basic `foreach` loops. If you don't even post an attempt nobody is going to help you.

Comment: i don't have an idea how to do it

Comment: @JotheesP Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to isolate the parts you need then just foreach it and multiply.

```
$arr1 = Array(
    "2" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 2,
            "id" => 2
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 1,
            "id" => 1
        ),

    "3" => Array
        (
            "quantity" => 1,
            "id" => 3
        ));

$arr2 = Array(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "2Bed Room",
            "room" => 6,
            "bed" => 12,
            "price" => 2800,
            "available_room" => 6,
            "available_bed" => 12,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "3Bed Room",
            "room" => 12,
            "bed" => 36,
            "price" => 3800,
            "available_room" => 12,
            "available_bed" => 36,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "Dormitory",
            "room" => 8,
            "bed" => 16,
            "price" => 750,
            "available_room" => 8,
            "available_bed" => 16,
            "extra_bed" => 500,
        ));

$arrone = array_column($arr1, "quantity", "id"); // arrone is now  associatvie array with quantity as value
$arrtwo = array_column($arr2, "price", "id"); // arrtwo is now associative array with price as value

foreach($arrone as $key => $val){
    $total[$key] = $arrtwo[$key] * $val; // multiply them and add them to total array
}

var_dump($total);
```

https://3v4l.org/NLpt9

In a real world you may need to make sure $key exists in $arrtwo. But if the data input is safe/secure this code will work.